# Howto Android unit test a PreferenceActivity and it's context

Tags: android

How can I set the context in the following class:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener 
...
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
```

when unit testing in Android using:

```
public class ReceiveSMSMonitorTest extends AndroidTestCase {
...
SettingsActivity settings = new SettingsActivity();    <-----
...
```

There is no constructor to send in the context with getContext(). Is there another way of doing it without modifying the original class? I like to use the context to get and check SharedPreferences.

Thanks!